# Do wives have to follow even Adharmic order of their husbands?

Tags: marriage, wife

It is the dharma of the wife to follow the orders of her husband . But what if the husband gives an order which is against the rule of dharma or is immoral ,then do the wife have to follow even that order ?

Comment: No, does not have to follow. If the husband was really following dharma he would not give such as order. So if a husband gives such an order he is not a follow of dharma.